# filewritting printwriter, fileoutputStream

Tags: java

so i'm trying to figure out what to change in my Output method because every time i write to the text file in the loop it just overwrites the last file...i'm not sure which constructor to use.

here is my code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TemperatureControl {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    System.out.print("=== Converting Temperature ===\n");
    // calls the temperature conversion method.
    convertTemperature();
}
public static void convertTemperature(){
    // Initialize scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // creating objects for the separate classes
    Celcius celcius = new Celcius();
    Kelvin kelvin = new Kelvin();
    Fahrenhieght fahrenheight = new Fahrenhieght();
    int selection = 0;
    while (true){
    try{
    // Asks user for their input 
    System.out.print("Enter 1 for Fahrenheit to Celsius\n"
            + "Enter 2 for Kelvin to Celsius\n"
            + "Enter 3 for Kelvin to Fahrenheit\n"
            + "Enter 4 for Celsius to Fahrenheit\n"
            + "Enter 5 for Fahrenheit to Kelvin\n"
            + "Enter 6 for Celsius to Kelvin\n"
            + "Enter -1 to Exit.\n" + "Your Option:");
    selection = input.nextInt();


    // depending on the selection from the user the program will execute the necessary decision. 
    if(selection == 1){
        System.out.print("Enter the temperature you wish to convert: ");
        double temperature = input.nextDouble();
        double c = celcius.FahrenheihtToCelcius(temperature);
        System.out.printf("The converted temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius is: %.1f\n", c);
        //outputting the file to a text document.
        Output("The converted temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius is:", c);
        }
    else if(selection == 2){
        System.out.print("Enter the temperature you wish to convert: ");
        double b = input.nextDouble();
        double k = celcius.KelvinToCelcius(b);
        System.out.printf("The converted temperature from Kelvin to Celsius is: %.1f\n", k);
        Output("The converted temperature from Kelvin to Celsius is:", k);
    }
    else if(selection == 3){
        System.out.print("Enter the temperature you wish to convert: ");
        double i = input.nextDouble();
        double f = fahrenheight.KelvinToFahrenheit(i);
        System.out.printf("The converted temperature from Kelvin to Fahrenheit is: %.1f\n", f);
        Output("The converted temperature from Kelvin to Fahrenheit is:", f);

    }
    else if(selection == 4){
        System.out.print("Enter the temperature you wish to convert: ");
        double o = input.nextDouble();
        double l = fahrenheight.CelsiusToFahrenheit(o);
        System.out.printf("The converted temperature from Celsius to Fahrenheit is: %.1f\n", l);
        Output("The converted temperature from Celsius to Fahrenheit is:", l);
    }
    else if(selection == 5){
        System.out.print("Enter the temperature you wish to convert: ");
        double a = input.nextDouble();
        double s = kelvin.FahrenheitToKelvin(a);
        System.out.printf("The converted temperature from Fahrenheit to Kelvin is: %.1f", s);
        Output("The converted temperature from Fahrenheit to Kelvin is:", s);
    }
    else if(selection == 6){
        System.out.print("Enter the temperature you wish to convert: ");
        double z = input.nextDouble();
        double x = kelvin.CelsiusToKelvin(z);
        System.out.printf("The converted temperature from Celsius to Kelvin is: %.1f\n", x);
        Output("The converted temperature from Celsius to Kelvin is:", x);
    }
    else if(selection == -1){
        System.out.println("Exiting program.");
        break;
    }
    else{
            System.out.println("That is not a valid selecion.");
        }
    }

    // checks to see if string values other numerical values were entered 
and catches the error. 
    catch(InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("That is not a valid selection");
        input.next();
    }
    }
}
public static void Output(String s, double temp) {
    // try catch exceptions to check if the file was properly read and output. 
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
         out = new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
     out.printf("%s %.1f", s, temp);
     out.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an extremely simple error. Your problem is the method called Ouput(convention in java we begin methods with a lowercase letter). You are creating a new file every time instead of appending to the file. To do this change the line `out = new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt"));` to `out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt", true));` The true part tells it not to flush the buffer and instead to append to the file. Furthermore, also change your FileNotFoundException to an IOException.

Comment: thanks so much for pointing this out to me. it was pulling my hair out.

Comment: shaddyy, if this solved your problem, you should mark this answer as accepted (the check mark on the left). This way, the question will be out of SO's pipeline.